# Unable to run Java program with vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have upgraded my Visual Studio Code to version details: 
**Version**: 1.38.1 (user setup)
**Commit**: b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0
**Date**: 2019-09-11T13:35:15.005Z
**Electron**: 4.2.10
**Chrome**: 69.0.3497.128
**Node.js**: 10.11.0
**V8**: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
**OS**: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362

Every time I run the simple **HelloWorld program** written in Java, vscode prompt the following error

> Extension host terminated unexpectedly

I think some extension related to Debugger of Java is incompatible with the vscode version or it may be deprecated.

[image: Problem]

Any help will be appreciate,
Thanks

Comment: Read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial. It's very helpful for vscode + java

Answer (score 0):

Did you install jdk? Are you using visual studio code ? If yes then do this:

Please install necessary extensions and add an extension that create a .class file to excecute that .java file or you can simply use cmd

In cmd goto your file location and enter following

1. `javac filename.java` (this creates a .class file) then enter
2. `java filename.java` (you will see your output in cmd)